# swift fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value in adMob

Tags: swift, admob, fatal-error

I try to ad adMob in my app. 
After release of my app, adMob not worked.
I tried to fix it, but now i have the fatal error...
What is problem in line "bannerView.adUnitID = ...."?
Thanks...

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, GADBannerViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var bannerView: GADBannerView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //ADMOB
    self.bannerView = GADBannerView()
    bannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-...." // THIS LINE IS FATAL ERROR
    bannerView.delegate = self
    self.bannerView.rootViewController = self

    var request: GADRequest = GADRequest()
    //request.testDevices = [""]
    self.bannerView.loadRequest(request)
    }
```

Comment: can you post your fixed code please? having the same issue, but unable to fix(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, your main issue is you have `bannerView` set as an IBOutlet to a `GADBannerView`. Then, you set it explicitly in the line

```
self.bannerView = GADBannerView()
```

So either use the IBOutlet or don't. If you hooked up your outlet to your storyboard, then you don't need to initialize it and should delete this line. Or, get rid of the outlet if you're not hooking it to anything.